# Form submit with a field Date

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

i have a form :

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="lostcard" action="enregistrerLostCard" id="formCard_Lost">
[...]
<form:input path="dateDeclaration" type="text"/>
[...]
<input  value="enregistrer" type="button" onclick="saveformAjax()"/>
[...]
```

where `lostcard` is a bean who have a field Date `dateDeclaration`.

When I try to submit this form with ajax

```
function saveformAjax() {
$.ajax({
    url : 'enregistrerLostCard',
    type: 'POST',
    data:$('#formCard_Lost').serialize(),
    success : function(responce) {   
        [...]
    }
});
```

}

But when I delete `<form:input path="dateDeclaration" type="text"/>` the form submit normally.

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/enregistrerLostCard") 
public  @ResponseBody
void enregistrerLostCard(@ModelAttribute(value="lostcard") Lostcard lostcard) { 

    System.out.println("enregistrerLostCard"); 

}
```

My `Lostcast` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lostcard", catalog = "gestion")
public class Lostcard implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer id;
private String nom;
private String prenom;
private String cin;
private Date dateDeclaration;
private Date dateDuplicata;
private String annexeAdmin;
    [...]
```

Comment: Let's see your handler method.

Comment: And now let's see your `Lostcast` class and and the value you enter into the input field for `dateDeclaration`.

Comment: i update my post :) for the input field `dateDeclaration` i didn't put anything i left it with empty entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally it's work now thanks to [gerrytan](http://gerrydevstory.com/2013/05/21/binding-date-form-input-on-spring-mvc/)

I add at my `Lostcast` class  :

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date dateDeclaration;
```